# How do I go about getting the trusted CAs to add to my certificate store

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm curious how one would go about creating a certificate store similar to what Firefox or Windows uses but for my own application. I can figure out how to create a keystore. But how do I go about getting the trusted CAs to add to it?

Comment: Right-click on the green-lock of your browser, view the certificate and download. Also you can download the certificates from the trusted service provider's web page

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something more official. For example firefox has  100s of CAs. Do they collect them from each organization or is there someplace to download all popular CA certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any central organization that decides the certificates to be accepted by each browser. Each one has its own process to accept a new CA

- **Firefox**: process defined in https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA
- **Chrome**: use the root certificate store of the underlying operating system. [See](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy)

In the Chrome link you can see the references to [Microsoft Root Certificate Program](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3281.aspx) and [Apple Root Certificate Program](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ca_program.html), and the way to do it for **Linux** and **android**

**European Union** has its own legislation where each member publish a **Trusted Service List** which are linked in a [central list](https://ec.europa.eu/information_society/policy/esignature/trusted-list/tl-mp.xml). All territories have the legal obligation to accept certificates issued by any provider in the list . It is XML and designed to be processed automatically but browsers do not use